# File Locking Issue When Using Custom MSBuild Task in Development Mode

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget-package, msbuild-task

I am developing a custom MSBuild task following the guidance outlined in the [Microsoft Example](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/msbuild/custom-task-code-generation#development). The development workflow is not good because whenever I change my task and I want to test it, to do that I need to restart VS (I'm testing the task by referencing it in another project using `<UsingTask>`).

I replicated the suggested code snippet into my `MSBuildConsoleExample.csproj` file, and the file was generated successfully.

However, upon making modifications to the task implementation in `AppSettingStronglyTyped` project, I encounter an error during the build process. The specific error message is as follows:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning MSB3026 Could not copy "obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\AppSettingStronglyTyped.dll" to "bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\AppSettingStronglyTyped.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\AppSettingStronglyTyped.dll' because it is being used by another process. The file is locked by: "MSBuild.exe (760)" AppSettingStronglyTyped D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    4734
```

This issue significantly impedes local testing and development, requiring a restart of Visual Studio each time changes are made. I am seeking guidance or potential solutions to overcome this file locking problem in order to facilitate smoother local development.

For reference, the relevant code snippet can be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2681x465hyi1n3w0oju0h/custom-task-code-generation.zip?rlkey=zugjk8praz1197t2qdwb166jr&dl=0)

**Current workaround**

Currently, to address the file locking issue, I follow a workaround by restarting Visual Studio, rebuilding the `AppSettingStronglyTyped`, and then rebuilding the `MSBuildConsoleExample`.

Ideally, the expected behavior would allow seamless updates to the generated files within `AppSettingStronglyTyped` without necessitating a restart of Visual Studio. This way, changes made in `AppSettingStronglyTyped` would reflect in `MSBuildConsoleExample` without the need for a full restart of the development environment.

**Attempt with Local Nuget Package**

In an attempt to mitigate the issue, I experimented with using a local NuGet feed and generating a new NuGet package with each build iteration. However, this approach exposed a Visual Studio caching problem. It required a waiting period of approximately 3 minutes to update the NuGet cache or, again, necessitated the reopening of Visual Studio to resolve the caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio includes a pack of tools, if you try to restart it, the steps will be very slow.

Since the situation is the msbuild lock the file, you could just kill msbuild.

Open the Task manager, and then end the msbuild task to release the file.

[image]

This way should be faster than what you are doing now.